# PHP switch() with in_array() and range() not working correctly

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to create a function that returns the compass points given the angle from 0 to 360 degrees, and came across this function. It works, except when the angle is 0... And 
I cannot understand why this code does not work:

```
echo rosaventos(0);
function rosaventos($grau,$slim=true){
    switch($grau) {
        case in_array($grau, range(0,22,1)):{
            $prnt = "N";
            break;
        }
        case in_array($grau, range(23,67,1)):{
            $prnt = "NE";
            break;
        }
        case in_array($grau, range(68,112,1)):{
            $prnt = "E";
            break;
        }
        case in_array($grau, range(113,157,1)):{
            $prnt = "SE";
            break;
        }
        case in_array($grau, range(158,202,1)):{
            $prnt = "S";
            break;
        }
        case in_array($grau, range(203,247,1)):{
            $prnt = "SO";
            break;
        }
        case in_array($grau, range(248,292,1)):{
            $prnt = "O";
            break;
        }
        case in_array($grau, range(293,337,1)):{
            $prnt = "NO";
            break;
        }
        case in_array($grau, range(338,360,1)):{
            $prnt = "N";
            break;
        }
        default: {
            $prnt = "-?-";
        }
    }
    if($slim){
        return $prnt;
    }else{
        return $prnt."-Extended";
    }   
}
```

The result is

```
NE
```

, but it should be

```
N
```

.

Can anybody explain why, and how to fix it?

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

Established that I made an error in the code, and the conditions should be like:

```
(...)
swich(true) {
(...)
```

and it's an inefficient way of doing things:
I found that if I try

```
echo rosaventos("0");
```

using the original code, the result is the correct

```
N
```

?!?!

Comment: `case` declarations should only contain static values, not expressions. They're not `if` conditions.

Comment: `in_array()` returns a Boolean `true` or `false`: so your switch on `$grau` is comparing `$grau` with those possible Boolean values; this is a case where a series of `if... elseif... elseif...` statements may well be a better option; or using a lookup against an array of your range values

Comment: Get rid of the curly braces around each case statement:`

     switch($grau) {
        case in_array($grau, range(0,22,1)):
            $prnt = "N";
            break;
        case in_array($grau, range(23,67,1)):
            $prnt = "NE";
            break;
        `

Comment: You can `switch(true) {}` to have comparison conditions in your cases (which return boolean true or false). I answered a question exactly like this recently, will just try and find it.

Comment: For the record, I disagree with @MarkBaker and @mario (with regards to using this feature). Conditions in switch statements work well, there is no need to use if-else blocks. I would recommend using `switch(true){` though, as @scrowler mentioned.

Comment: You are correct, i was tring to compare numbers with conditions. Thanks.

Comment: I was not get there because it worked on the other numbers correctly...

Comment: @Christian I agree with Mark Baker. While `switch(true)` will work, it's backwards and confusing. It would be appropriate in a Code Golf or Obfuscated programming contest, but poor style for production code.

Comment: `in_array ($number, range(x, y))` is also a very poor way to do `$number >= x && $number <= y`

Comment: @Barmar it is confusing to who never used it. OOP is also confusing to people coming from procedural programming. I think it's way more elegant than having a multitude of if-else blocks.

Comment: It's not a common programming idiom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you evenly divide your angles between the compass points, may I suggest you try a simple calculation and map lookup instead:

```
$dir = array("N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SO", "O", "NO", "N");

$grau = 100;
$compass = $dir[floor( ($grau + 22.5) / 45 )];
```

Comment: It's a elegant solution... Thanks